# Rejection of iOS app due repackaged website

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

I have a travel app which showcases the content related to the travel platform like "**Offers**", "**Essentials**", "**Attractions**" and "**Ships for different routes**" "**facilities in each ships**". But the "**Booking**" feature we are covering with help of that app's corresponding website.

The workflow is as follows, if user clicks on "**Create Booking**" button, it takes the user to website displayed in WKWebview which is presented modally. User can book the  tickets and once he close the WKWebview after booking the tickets, my tickets screen which is a different tab view gets updated.

I just wanted to clarify, is there any chance that my app will get rejected as it is doing the "**Create Booking**" feature by displaying the website in WKWebView.

Specifically we like to know, whether the above workflow is against "**4.2 Minimum Functionality**" guideline mentioned in apple appstore review guideline(https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

It will be really helpful, if your team is able to provide us insights regarding the above clarification
Thanking in advance,
Smitha

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably, no-one on Ask Different is able to speak on behalf of Apple's reviewers.

## Contact the App Store

The reviews can feel capricious, so do ask your question to Apple directly. Contact the App Store staff via the *Support and Contact Us* link at the base of the [App Store Connect](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/) page. They are best placed to help you.